# No gulpfile found

Tags: node.js, gulp, laravel-5

I am new in laravel. I am trying the command nmp install. it does not work. Then as shown in their official documentation, I tried

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

but I was getting access denied error.
So I gave

```
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

It seemed to give me some correct result. then I gave

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

but it says that,

`"npm WARN vagrant@1.0.0 No description npm WARN vagrant@1.0.0 No repository field."`
 I tried

```
npm install -d
```

though the result ended with "ok" (after running the command the first line said "it worked if it ends with ok"), it still contains 
`""npm WARN vagrant@1.0.0 No description npm WARN vagrant@1.0.0 No repository field."`
 And when I gave the command

```
gulp
```

the answer was no gulpfile found. In my project there is a gulpfile.js file (I am not sure about which gulpfile it is talking :\ )

what to do? My node version is `V5.12.0`

Comment: did you ran "gulp" from project folder?

Comment: can you post the directory path on your terminal when you run "gulp" command

Comment: vagrant@homestead:~/Code/laravel$ gulp

Comment: What version of Laravel you are running?

Comment: If you are explicitly using something like  `gulp --gulpfile custom_gulpfile.js` and you get this error - check the file path, if the path is wrong you still get the same error :)

Answer (score 21):

In my case, in order to solve the error, 'no gulpfile found' I wrongly called the configuration file as `gulp.js` instead of `gulpfile.js`.

So just make sure you didn't misspell the file.

Another possible reason why you might get this error is when you are running the gulp command in the wrong directory.
Make sure the gulpfile.js is not inside another folder but within the project folder.

Answer (score 12):

This error means that gulp doesn't find gulpfile.js to follow the instructions. To solve this error we need to add gulpfile.js to our directory root by running the command.

Create gulpfile.js and then add

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () { 
    console.log('Hello Gulp!') 
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to use npm run watch instead of gulp?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. I created the `gulpfile.js` file through explorer so it was incorrectly named `gulpfile.js.txt` which prevented the gulp command finding it. This only became obvious when I opened the project in a text editor and I saw the extension.

Comment: thank man. I spelled it fulpfile.js and wondering why the heck it is giving me that error :D

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem in Laravel 6. I solved it by steps:

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev gulp
npx mkdirp yourProjectName
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

**Create a gulpfile:Using your text editor, create a file named gulpfile.js in your project root with these contents:**

```
function defaultTask(cb) {
  // place code for your default task here
  cb();
}

exports.default = defaultTask
```

Full Resource here:
https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start

Hope this helps ypu

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for creating this issue, I also had it.
The fix for me was to put **gulpfile.js in the root directory**.

Answer (score 0):

After running 'yo' to create your new project, use 'cd' command to jump to the the root directory of your new project, then you can run 'gulp' commands.

Answer (score 0):

My `gulpFile.js` was not in my root directory as expected!

I had to find the file, change to that directory, and then run `gulp forever --react`. (I have a React project.)

Answer (score 0):

You must have saved the project files in a subfolder instead of current folder.

Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)?: SharePoint Online only (latest)
Where do you want to place the files?: Use the current folder

If you have selected "**Create a subfolder with solution name**"

Then change the directory cd "path of the project"
Then run

gulp trust-dev-cert

gulp serve

Answer (score 0):

```
gulpfile.js > 
const gulp = require('gulp')
gulp.task('style', function () {
console.log(1)
}
> gulp style > 1 // true
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider before running gulp task runner:

gulp filename should be **gulpfile.js**

**gulpfile.js** should be in root folder

make sure all tasks performing related libraries are installed eg: gulp-concat, gulp-concat gulp-minify-css

minify css snippet :

```
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulp = require('gulp');


gulp.task('styles', async function () {
    gulp.src(['src/styles/*.css'])
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'));
});
```

Run the required task from root folder where **gulfile.js** exists

Answer (score -1):

If you have the gulpfile in your root directory and there are the tasks so maybe the problem is the version.

I ran `gulp -v` and the output was:

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.0
```

To fix it I ran `npm install - gulp@3.9.0` to keep both the same and the error:

> No gulpfile found

Stopped to be shown