# I'm trying to run gulp serve and says 'No gulpfile found'. I'm new with Nodejs. I don't know if I the gulp path is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I think that maybe the path of gulp is wrong. But  i'm not sure.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import autoprefixer from 'gulp-autoprefixer';
import cleanCSS from 'gulp-clean-css';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import babelify from 'babelify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import jsmin from 'gulp-jsmin';
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
import wpPot from 'gulp-wp-pot';
import sort from 'gulp-sort';

const reload = browserSync.reload;
reloadFiles = ['./script.js', './style.css', './**/*.php'];
proxyOptions = {
  proxy: 'localhost/dakar/',
  notify: false
   };

gulp.task('server', () => browserSync.init(reloadFiles, proxyOptions));
```

I expect to run the gulp server, but the output is [12:07:16] No gulpfile found

Comment: What is the name of gulp file ? Do we've the package gulp-cli install ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file name isn't gulpfile.js.

Also look into this thread if the above didn't solve your problem: [No gulpfile found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937095/no-gulpfile-found)