# Gulpfile not found even though it clearly exists

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to help a remote coworker install gulp on Windows so he can compile one of our JavaScript projects locally. An employee before me has been trying to help this remote coworker for over a year before I got here to little avail, so there may be some crud left over from that time at the root of the issue, but I've done what I thought to be a reasonable start from scratch and I continue to have the same problem.

I've sent him the project folder exactly cloned as I have it, minus the node_modules folder. I had him uninstall and reinstall Node first using the first [three steps of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows/20711410#20711410) followed by redownloading the MSI from NodeJS.org to reinstall fresh. Then, in the working directory, I had him run

```
PS C:\Users\Coworker\Path\To\Project>npm ci
```

to install gulp. gulp and its various extensions are the only modules in the package.json folder, and the package-lock.json is simply the result of us successfully installing these packages recently. Contents of `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-coffee": "latest",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-concat-sourcemap": "latest",
    "gulp-connect": "latest",
    "gulp-minifier": "latest",
    "gulp-minify-css": "latest",
    "gulp-remove-logging": "latest",
    "gulp-resolve-dependencies": "latest",
    "gulp-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "latest",
    "gulp-util": "latest",
    "gulp-watch": "latest",
    "gulp-wrap": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "natives": "^1.1.6"
  }
}
```

I also had him uninstall and reinstall `gulp-cli` globally.

```
npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Running `gulp --version` displays the correct, expected output:

```
PS C:\Users\Coworker\Path\To\Project>gulp --version
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.0
```

This matches the output on my Windows machine, where everything works fine.

When we finally have him run `gulp` in the project directory, it simply gives:

```
PS C:\Users\Coworker\Path\To\Project> gulp
No gulpfile found
```

The only helpful question already on Stack Overflow for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937095/no-gulpfile-found/47406977), and every answer there is some form of "add a gulpfile". But there **is** a gulpfile.js in the working directory. It has the correct name and file extension. It is formatted properly. It's an exact duplicate of the file in my own local directory, which when I run the same command, it gulps flawlessly. What could be causing gulp to not recognize the gulpfile is present? Could gulp be misconfigured and trying to run with a different working directory, despite the directory it is being called in? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Try adding npm script in package.json tht will use the local gulp from the project folder

Comment: What's the output of `dir` in the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the gulpfile:

```
gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.js

gulp --gulpfile C:\Users\Coworker\Project\gulpfile.js
```

Comment: I guess this worked. Don't know why gulp doesn't just find the file, Works On My Machine(TM).